# Error installing couchDB on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, 20.04, couchdb

I'm having issues installing couchDB on ubuntu 20.04. These are the steps I did already:

```
curl -L https://couchdb.apache.org/repo/bintray-pubkey.asc | sudo apt-key add
echo "deb https://apache.bintray.com/couchdb-deb focal main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install couchdb
```

And I get the following issue:

```
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 couchdb : Depends: libmozjs-68-0 (>= 68.6.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then I tried installing manually the libmozjs-68-0 with:
`sudo apt install libmozjs-68-0`

And I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package libmozjs-68-0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libmozjs-68-0' has no installation candidate
```

Any suggeestions?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories) . As it is in place https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libmozjs-68-0 .

Comment: @N0rbert thanks for the tip. Yes it solved. I didn't use the method described but I copied the /etc/apt/sources.list for another clean install of ubuntu and it's working now. For some reason this ubunto version didn't have the source_list complete.